# Sum and Count in Room - no such column for an alias

Tags: android, alias, android-room

So I recently jumped into Room and I am facing a curious issue regarding aliases.

I will simplify the classes so my example can be clearer.
Let's say I have bills which can contain some products.

I want to get a list of bills with their products for a period of time (days, hours, ...).

I'd need the entities Bill and Product :

> **Entity** Bill.java

```
@Entity  
public class Bill{  
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  
    int id;  
    Date date;  
}
```

> **Entity** Product.java

```
@Entity  
public class Product{  
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;  
    int bill_id;  
    BigDecimal price;  
    String name;
}
```

I have a POJO representing a bill with its products.

> **POJO** BillWithProducts.java :

```
public class BillWithProducts{
    @Embedded
    public Bill bill;  

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "bill_id")  
    public List<Product> products;  
}
```

And the Daos for the queries :

> **Dao** BillDao.java

```
@Dao  
public abstract class BillDao{  
    @Query("select * from bill")  
    public abstract List<Bill> getAllBills();  

    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from bill where date between :startDate and :endDate")  
    public abstract List<BillWithProducts> getBillsWithProductsByDate(long startDate, long endDate);  
}
```

> **Dao** ProductDao.java :

```
@Dao
public abstract class ProductDao{  
    @Query("select * from product")  
    public abstract List<Product> getAllProducts();  
}
```

So far so good.
But for display preferences, I want products with the same name on a single line and having their quantities and prices adding accordingly.

For this purpose (and because my Product.java has a lot of informations that are not needed here ; keeping things minimal), I created a POJO of my Product class.

> **POJO** ProductMinimal.java :

```
public class ProductMinimal{
    int id;  
    int bill_id;  
    BigDecimal price;  
    String name;  
    int quantity;  
    BigDecimal sumPrices;  
}
```

I edited the Relation in BillWithProducts.java to get a list of ProductMinimal.

> **Edited POJO** BillWithProducts.java :

```
public class BillWithProducts{  
    @Embedded  
    Bill bill; 

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "bill_id", entity = Product.class)  
    public List<ProductMinimal> productsMinimal; //<-- error pointing here
}
```

And added the query in ProductDao.java.

> **Edited dao** ProductDao.java :

```
@Dao
public abstract class ProductDao{  
    @Query("select * from product")  
    public abstract List<Product> getAllProducts();  

    @Query("select id, bill_id, price, name, " +  
    "count(*) as quantity, sum(price) as sumPrices " + 
    "from product " +  
    "group by name")  
    public abstract List<ProductMinimal> getAllProductsMinimal();
}
```

Finally, the reason what I am here for is that I got this error pointing on the relation in BillWithProducts.java...

> error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
>   missing database (no such column: quantity)

Of course there is not such column, it's an alias...

I tried :
- adding simple quotes for the aliases like "count(*) as 'quantity'"
- removing the count(*) ; the error went to sumPrices
- embedding Product in ProductPojo (thus having "select *" and lots of useless fields)
- I even tried using as an alias an existing column of Product...

Have some of you already faced a similar case?

EDIT : 
I tried getting the bill_id in that quantity alias like :

```
@Query("select id, bill_id, price, name, " +  
        "bill_id as quantity " + 
        "from product " +  
        "group by name")  
public abstract List<ProductMinimal> getAllProductsMinimal();
```

and still getting that no such column error so it is not linked to the sum or count operation.

EDIT2 : edited the post to include the POJO BillWithProducts.java (it was in my code but not in the post).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for the test I tried adding the quantity column in my product table and the code runned smoothly.
The thing is that my *productsMinimal* list in **BillWithProducts.java** contained all the products with the quantity field at 0.
It was like the query didn't take into consideration the group by and count.
(I removed  this quantity column, it was added just for the tests)

I then tried to query my database with a similar scenario but "outside of" this Bill/Product Relation with a **getDatabase().productDao().getAllProductsMinimal(bill_id)** call.

> **Dao** ProductDao.java :

```
@Dao
public abstract class ProductDao{  
    @Query("select * from product")  
    public abstract List<Product> getAllProducts();  

    @Query("select id, bill_id, price, name, " +  
    "count(*) as quantity, sum(price) as sumPrices " + 
    "from product " +  
    "group by name " + 
    "where bill_id = :bill_id")  
    public abstract List<ProductMinimal> getAllProductsMinimal(int bill_id);
}
```

Here I could get the result I was aiming for!
So what I ended up thinking is that the @Relation annotation doesn't allow any condition.

At the end I kept the original @Relation, got all my Products, having name redundancy and created my own list with quantity and sum by name in java from the original list.
As there won't be a large number of products by bill and because the list of products is only displayed on a more details screen, building my list on the click to this more details button doesn't delay the display of data needed.

Comment: label name to col name for count or sum is working. thanks